# TCP Socket Testing

Tags: c#, networking, automation, tcp, integration-testing

I have a class that receives data from a socket. What i'm looking for is a pre-existing application for testing sockets. For example I pass configuration data to the app which then fires up and sends a data to my 'receive' socket. It should also output debug information.

Ive looked into hercules but I don't believe I can interop with it, through a command line or COM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd build something around [Ncat](http://nmap.org/ncat/).